# how to show gmail contact in android after signin with google in codenaoneone

Tags: codenameone

I was working on the social chat demo in codenameone, after followed the tutorial to the last stage, I ran it on my laptop with the simulator, which worked fine when signin with Google. Now, I build the project as Android, it was successful on the CN1 portal. After installing this debug apk on my tablet, it does not list the contact as it does on my laptop. Pls is there anything I will add that will make it work for me on phone? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the release APK as it's certificate will match the one you declared in the SHA1 stage. The debug APK uses a debug certificate.

You need to follow the stages carefully as the device uses native login and needs the certificate and related material to be valid.

Comment: It has populated the gmail contacts on my phone after installing the released apk. Also I can send and receive message on my phones. Kudos to Shai Almog. The tutorial really helpful. Thanks